# How style the inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Im using the angular material tab. The problem is the tabs arent the same size. Depend on the content. So I wonder if I can make the inner `ng-scope` be the size of the outter `ng-scope`.

This is a simplify version of the resulting `md-tab-content`

```
<md-tab-content id="tab-content-3" class="_md ng-scope md-active">
  <div class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  </div>
</md-tab-content>
```

The thing is can I reference an angular element? And do something Like

```
md-tab-content > div.ng-scope {
   and set size here = outside size?

   //worst case set the height by hand
   height: 252px;
}
```

Here the inner `div` height is 57 when outter `md-tab-content` is 252

[image]

**tabs code**

```
<div id="tree-footer-container" ng-cloak>
    <md-tabs id="jc" md-selected="selectedIndex">
        <md-tab   class="fullSize" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled">
             <md-tab-label>
                    <div style="float: left;padding-right: 10px;">{{tab.title}}</div>
             </md-tab-label>
             <md-tab-body>
                 <div flex style="background:blue" class="demo-tab tab{{$index%4}}" ng-include="tab.url">
                 </div>
             </md-tab-body>
         </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the material layout directives:

```
<md-tab-content id="..." layout="column" class="...">
  <div flex class="...">
  </div>
</md-tab-content>
```

Comment: those are autogenerated. i didnt create any of those, Is your answer still relevant? because I need more details.

Comment: It might be. Try it.

Comment: How? again is autogenerated. I can only try creating a CSS to alter the elements generated

Comment: Oh I gotcha. You might want to setup a code snippet. There is an interesting note on tab stretching here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs. Did you try `md-stretch-tabs=always`?

Comment: yes, that looks like the right property, but the example doesnt show how to use :(.  I mean where to  put it? `md-tabs` or `md_tab`

Comment: `md-stretch-tabs` is for the label tab, not the content area and go on the `md-tabs` container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all your classes but I think this would fix it with jQuery:

```
var newWidth = $('.ng-isolate-scope').outerWidth;
$('.classOfOtherDiv').width(newWidth);
```

First you get the outer width of the one div then apply it to the other. Did that work?

Comment: That could work, but where I put that code so if things change get refreshed? that is why I was  thinking on CSS.

Comment: You could place that in a function then call the function on resize/load/ready. For resize:

`$(window).resize(function(){resizeWidthFuntion()});`

Comment: It seems like you must have solved this, can you mark it answered?

Comment: this doesnt work, because the class `ng-scope` is every where

Comment: Can you post the full code from the page? There is usually some identifier that you can use to grab it with jQuery selectors.

Comment: Please post the entire code, without the full scope of your layout and classes it's a guessing game with little pieces of the code.

Comment: that is all the code. the rest is autogenerated for angular.js

Comment: Please post the code that is generated, that's what we are going to work on once the page is rendered